# Send data from a QR scan (text) in an iOS app to be stored in SQL database

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I have a QR scanner that will read the text that is embedded and I would like it to store the information into the SQL database.  The database is setup, and the php site handles the input correctly if I enter manually into the URL (ex. `www.blah.com/input.php?name=Bob`).  However, I cannot figure out how to get the information to submit to my php site and/or put the information into the database.  I'm sure there is a better/easier way.  Below is the code I am using:

```
NSString *url= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://blah.com/input.php?name=%@", name];
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

Then this is my current php setup:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');


$db_conn = new  PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db','user','pwd');
$db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$date = date("m/d/y");
$time = date("h:i:sa");
//$name = "";
$name = ($_GET['name']); 


$qry = $db_conn->prepare('INSERT INTO CheckIn(`date`,`time`,`name`) VALUES          (:date,:time,:name)');
$qry->bindParam(':date', $date);
$qry->bindParam(':time', $time);
$qry->bindParam(':name', $name);

$qry->execute();

if ($qry) { $message = "success"; }
else { $message = "failed"; }

echo utf8_encode($message);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSURLConnection class to send synchronous / asynchronous request.

Here is an example for the synchronous request:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                           returningResponse:&response 
                                                       error:&err];
```